# How to set up FQDN with Dynamic IP?

Tags: dns, dyndns, dynamic-ip

Can I setup my www.example.com address when I have a dynamic external ip adress (no router) and if so whats needed to make it work?

The server is already installed with Ubuntu Server 12.04.3 and LAMP packages and works.
I would like to use a domain name instead of the ip address since it changes.

Comment: no-ip.com is the only free provider for a FQDN now.  There used to be a few, but they don't do it anymore AFAIK.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a [DNS hosting service](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DNS_hosting_service) that provides [dynamic DNS](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/DynamicDNS) services, and follow their instructions to configure your server. You'll likely be instructed to install a program like [ddclient](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/ddclient/).

Recommendations for DNS hosting services are beyond the scope of Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: Thanks for the reply seems i have no go that road, was kinda hoping some software could do the trick localy nowdays.

Answer (score 1):

I use a dynamic dns provider such as dyndns* and then alias the fqdn to the name that is provided by the dynamic dns service.  For example dyndns provides a hostname such as myhouse.dyndns.org and then a simple cname alias is created pointing www.example.com to myhouse.dyndns.org and voila!

- this is not an endorsement for dyndns service, I am not associated with their service nor do I recommend it, but it is an example of how this can be done.

Answer (score 1):

By the contents, this has more to do with your DNS provider then Ubuntu. If your server works using the IP, then the only thing that you need is a DNS provider that offers Dynamic DNS services (like DynDNS in your tags, or OpenDNS, etc....). You will need to pay both, the domain name (1 time pay) and the DNS to maintain it. Then configure Apache to resolve correctly the FQND and you are set.

Comment: acctually its more on ubuntu since i need to know what my options are in relation to what i have for isp and os

Comment: @user212469 if you type your IP and the thing works, then nothing has to be done in Ubuntu except installing maybe a tool that will update your IP's. Also, when accepting answers, do not comment others unless they are not clear or not covered by other answers.

Answer (score 1):

Adding to other answers:

I'd recommend using a static IP since dynamic DNS inherently brings potential problems related to caching:  Even after the IP is updated, it can take tens of minutes before it propagates to most of the Internet.  And in some places it can be even worse since sadly not all local DNS servers / clients respect TTLs properly.

Combined with how often IP changes and the costs for DDNS itself and costs of downtime, actually paying for the static IP might come cheaper.

Comment: Well unfortunally getting a static ip adress is not possible with this isp so i have to make do

Comment: @user212469 Strange, when looking for VPS provider in my country (Czech) I simply chose the cheapest one and had the first static IP free (or at least it was not possible to have a VPS *without* static IP).  So your situation kind of struck me as "what an injustice!"... :)  Maybe situation with non-VPS hosting is different though.  Or the prophecy was right: we really **are** getting low on IPs! :D

Answer (score 0):

In order to use the dynamic DNS client, you first need to register at least one hostname (actually a fully qualified domain name—FQDN) with DynDNS.com.

The dynamic DNS client can work with the the Dynamic Hosts option, which is the option to use if you don't own a domain name, but you want to host a server on your network and have people reach it by entering a domain name.

Dynamic hosts are free to register with DynDNS.com, and allow you to associate a
dynamic IP address with up to five of the static domain names that DynDNS.com provide.

Dynamic host IP associations require at least one update every 35 days to prevent them
from expiring.

<sup>Source:[How to Configure DDNS](http://www.google.jo/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CCcQFjAA&url=http://www.alliedtelesis.com/media/fount/how_to_note_alliedware/howto_config_ddns.pdf&ei=FvF7Uo3iFZOthQej1YDgDQ&usg=AFQjCNEngsqrOAcOVheip3Ze8awYlWYsfg)</sup>